# Adding key value based on condition in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Given:

```
a = {1:{"name":"John", "age":28}
     2:{"name":"Max", "age":24}
     3:{"name":"Paul", "age":27,"married":"yes"}
     4:{"name":"Richard", "age":23,"married":"yes"}}
```

I want to update the dictionary with key as married and value as yes if age is greater than 25

Comment: What problem are you having? Loop over the dictionary elements, then use an `if` statement to update it.

Comment: This can be done in a single line using an interesting list comprehension:

    `{key : a[key] if a[key]['age'] < 25 else {**a[key], "married":"yes"} for key in a} `

returns

    {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': 28, 'married': 'yes'}, 
     2: {'name': 'Max', 'age': 24}, 
     3: {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 27, 'married': 'yes'}, 
     4: {'name': 'Richard', 'age': 23, 'married': 'yes'}} 

the line `{**a[key], "married":"yes"}` concatenates the a dict with a married field.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in a:
        if a[i]['age'] > 25:
            a[i]['married'] = "yes"
        else:
            a[i]['married'] = "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems straight forward, try something like:

```
a = {1:{"name":"John", "age":28},
     2:{"name":"Max", "age":24},
     3:{"name":"Paul", "age":27,"married":"yes"},
     4:{"name":"Richard", "age":23,"married":"yes"}}

for person in a.values():
    if person['age'] > 25:
        person['married'] = 'yes'

print(a)
```

Out:

```
{
 1: {'name': 'John', 'age': 28, 'married': 'yes'},
 2: {'name': 'Max', 'age': 24},
 3: {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 27, 'married': 'yes'},
 4: {'name': 'Richard', 'age': 23, 'married': 'yes'}
}
```